# How to write sql query for search engine for e commerce like filpkart or snapdeal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to make a search engine for E Commerce  like  flipkart or Snapdeal, so what should I do?

I have used FreeText or contains but not getting desired answer because FreeText or contains work only on exact word for example:

This is the table

```
Item_Title
-------------------
BedSheet
HandBag
```

my Query is :

```
Select  * FROM tblName WHERE freetext(Item_Title,'bed sheet')
```

in this case it does not work because it there is space between bed and sheet.
I am looking for that where user type bedsheet or bed sheet result should provide same,

In other case some times user make mistake in spelling suppose he will type badsheet so how it will pick near by.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Did you consider an actual search engine? Such as https://www.elastic.co/  or http://lucene.apache.org/solr/?

Comment: no,         Just I am looking for a  query

Comment: If you need to build an eCommerce site with real search, suggestions, faceting, more like this etc., take a look at Azure Search

Comment: freetext assigns an integer value to each word in a string; the simple solution is to strip all whitespace from the strings in both the table and the passed in varchar.

Comment: Ok Thanks for reply Mr. Adam Martin,                                                     But suppose some will make   spelling mistake like for bedsheet , he will type badsheet , in this case what should I do ?